# Create a Twitter Thread with Tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, automation, tweepy

So I'm trying to modify my Twitter bot. It's an account that strictly posts quotes from my favorite books. The issue I'm having is sometimes I like a quote that goes over the Twitter character limit, so I was wondering if there was a way that'll let me reply to my first tweet with the rest of the quote. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is possible.

You can use Tweepy's `API.update_status()` and pass the previous tweet's status_id in as a parameter (in_reply_to_status_id)

http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.update_status